# How to use a PNG logo instead of the circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, png

How can I use a transparent PNG image instead of clipping the svg.
Please help need a transparent PNG image instead of circle.

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/bhumikadas/pen/vYJEXKm)

Here is the Javascript

```
var section = document.querySelector('section');
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    var value = window.scrollY;
    section.style.clipPath = "circle("+ value +"px at center)"
 })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly,
you need to change CSS section like `background: url(/yourlink);`

Comment: Yes just see this accenture.com/in-en  bottom of the page see how the accenture logo is animating.

Answer (score 0):

It can be through specifying `height` `width` and giving `border-radius` to the image .
And value change on scroll

```js
var section = document.querySelector('section');
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
        var value = window.scrollY;
        section.style.height =  value +"px"
        section.style.width = value +"px"
    })
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
}

section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;*/
  background: url(https://www.prixgen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/mission.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  border-radius:500px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 200vh;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 100px;
}

.container h2 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  top: 250px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Join us</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 class="title">Join us for Better Future</h2>
  <section></section>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is not the solution, how can i replace the Circle through a PNG logo. Please check the URL accenture.com/in-en go to the bottom of the page and see the logo animation what i am looking for ...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve as it is not very clear be more specific

Comment: The Circle coming from Left, need it on center. I need a PNG or Vector Logo instead of Circle.

Comment: If you can describe with a video or pic it will be easy of what you wanted to do